# Why VirtualBox won't allow running both IE 7 and IE 8 with Win XP downloadable free from Microsoft?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

The free virtual hard drive images from Microsoft:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&DisplayLang=en

is good for testing apps or running apps on Win XP on a Mac or Win 7 system...
But I have wondered why on the Mac, the VirtualBox won't allow running both the IE 7 and IE 8 virtual hard drive, saying that there is already such a device (or was it UUID).

Virtual PC can allow that... just wonder why VirtualBox won't allow that and is there any way to bypass that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
vboxmanage showhdinfo path\to\vhd
```

to show the UUIDs. If they are indeed identical, assign a new UUID with

```
VBoxManage internalcommands setvdiuuid path\to\vhd
```

or clone it with

```
VBoxManage clonehd
```

and then discard the original one.